# Eclipse doesn't remember last run program

Tags: java, eclipse

After I have run a program usually I can run it again by clicking on the big icon. But not on one certain workspace I have. (When I open the tooltip the name of the program is displayed too but again not here). Does anyone know what happened to this workspace?

[image]

After clicking the icon this window just opens

[image]

Comment: Is the file open in the editor a class (or something) called "DVAbwasserBerichte"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the preference window. Then go into `Run/Debug -> Launching` and check "`Always launch the previously launched application`"

[image: Launch previous application]